# Oracle Trigger before delete

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to add a trigger before deleting a user (from a users(id, name,...) table) so I can also delete the user's phone numbers (from a user_phone(user_id, phone) table):

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_before_delete 
BEFORE DELETE 
   ON users
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM user_phones WHERE user_id = :old.id;
END;
/
```

However I'm getting this error: *Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.*

I think it has something to do with :old.id ?

**EDIT:**
Even with the warning it seems to be working. When I delete a users, it also deletes its phone numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you run `show errors` in SQLPlus and share the output here please?

Comment: table `users_phone`  (defined in text up top) does not equal  `user_phones` (table defined on delete)... Which is it?  should the `delete FROM USERS_Phone where user_Id = :old.id;`?   Does `SELECT * from all_Tables where table_Name = 'USER_PHONES' ` return a record? what about `SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'USERS_PHONE'`

Comment: Even with the warning it seems to be working. When I delete a users, it also deletes its phone numbers.

Comment: As a side-note: a referential constraint with cascading delete will serve the same purpose as this trigger.

Comment: I agree with Allan: plus the cascading delete will probably be faster.

Answer (score -1):

when creating a trigger before delete or insert or update you can put this code and manipulate as you like
i hope this helped you little

```
BEGIN
if DELETING THEN ....
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Into BEFORE DELETE trigger this condition is always true. There is no any reason to use it.

Comment: Oh your right, thats my bad . If the trigger was before delete or insert or update